# Postgresql corrupt data in input function of custom base data type

Tags: c, postgresql, sql-function

I've created a custom type, `gp` to model the DND 5e currency system. I have defined custom input and output functions in `gp.c`:

```c
#include "postgres.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "fmgr.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

static const char* inputFormat = " %i %s2 ";
static const char* invalidFormat = "invalid input syntax for gp: \"%s\"";

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(gp_input);

Datum gp_input(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    char* raw = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    int32 amt;
    char unit[3];

    if (sscanf(raw, inputFormat, &amt, &unit[0]) != 2) {
        ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION), errmsg(invalidFormat, raw)));
    }

    switch(unit[1]) {
        case 'p':
            break;
        default:
            ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION), errmsg(invalidFormat, raw)));
    }
    switch(unit[0]) {
        case 'c':
            break;
        case 's':
            amt *= 10;
            break;
        case 'e':
            amt *= 50;
            break;
        case 'g':
            amt *= 100;
            break;
        case 'p':
            amt *= 1000;
            break;
        default:
            ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION), errmsg(invalidFormat, raw)));
    }

    int32* result = (int32*)palloc(sizeof(int32));
    *result = amt;

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(result);
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(gp_output);

Datum gp_output(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    int32* raw = (int32*)PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    int32 val = *raw;
    unsigned int bufsz = sizeof(unsigned char)*9 + 2;// allow up to 999999999[pgsc]p
    char* buf = (char*) palloc(bufsz+1); // +1 b/c '\0'

    if (val >= 10 && val % 10 == 0) {
        val /= 10;

        if (val >= 10 && val % 10 == 0) {
            val /= 10;

            if (val >= 10 && val % 10 == 0) {
                val /= 10;

                if (sprintf(buf, "%dpp", val) <= 0) {
                    ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_UNTRANSLATABLE_CHARACTER), errmsg("Bad value for gp")));
                }
            }
            else {
                if (sprintf(buf, "%dgp", val) <= 0) {
                    ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_UNTRANSLATABLE_CHARACTER), errmsg("Bad value for gp")));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (sprintf(buf, "%dsp", val) <= 0) {
                ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_UNTRANSLATABLE_CHARACTER), errmsg("Bad value for gp")));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (sprintf(buf, "%dcp", val) <= 0) {
            ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_UNTRANSLATABLE_CHARACTER), errmsg("Bad value for gp")));
        }
    }
    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(buf);
}
```

I know I'm not checking that the number is out-of-bounds or that the stored value fits in the buffer, but I'm not hitting that issue yet. My problem is that postgres seems to be editing, and in some cases corrupting, the values that I'm storing. I have this test SQL file:

```sql
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS gp CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TYPE gp;

CREATE FUNCTION gp_input(cstring) RETURNS gp AS '$libdir/gp.so' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE FUNCTION gp_output(gp) RETURNS cstring AS '$libdir/gp.so' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE TYPE gp (input=gp_input, output=gp_output);

CREATE TABLE test (val gp);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('12sp'), ('100gp'), ('1000cp'), ('101cp');
SELECT * FROM test;
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('101sp');
```

The output of that `SELECT` is:

```
  val  
-------
 12sp
 10pp
 1pp
 212cp
(4 rows)
```

So we can see that all values were properly stored and represented except for the last one: `101cp` gets stored as a pointer to the `int32` value `212`. Using `ereport` warnings, I was able to determine that right before the return in the input function, `result` points to the correct value: `101`. However, the pointer passed as an argument to my output function points to a value I didn't store: `212`. Somewhere between the end of my input code and the beginning of my output code, postgres corrupted that value. This *always* happens with the input string `101cp`, independent of the table's state or any other values being inserted at the same time.

But now the really weird part; that last `INSERT` crashes the client. Upon parsing that gp value, it prints the error:

```
psql:./gptest.sql:15: ERROR:  compressed data is corrupted
LINE 1: INSERT INTO test VALUES ('101sp');
                                 ^
```

This *always* happens with the value `101sp`, regardless of table state or any other values being inserted alongside it. Using `ereport` warnings, I was able to see that right before the return statement, `result` points to the correct value: `1010`. That also means that the crash is happening in that return macro expansion or in some under-the-hood code.

So I truly have no idea what's going on. I'm doing `palloc` so overwriting the memory shouldn't be allowed, and I can't think of any reason for values containing `101` to always have problems - and different problems depending on the units. An `int32` should be capable of storing the small values I'm testing, so it's not that. Idk if this is how it's supposed to be implemented, but I have checked and the pointer being passed to the output is NOT the same as the address of the `result` pointer for any of these values, so I assume it's doing some kind of `memcpy` incorrectly under the hood, but then idk how anyone can be expected to define a custom base data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) takes a ton of optional parameters, some of them relating to the physical layout of your data, and these need to agree with the structures your I/O functions are expecting/returning.

The docs don't seem to mention the defaults for these parameters, but the error mentioning "compressed data" suggests that your values are being [TOASTed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html), i.e. that `INTERNALLENGTH` is defaulting to `VARIABLE`. Such types are expected to start with a `varlena` header describing the total length of the value, which is certainly not what you're returning (though Postgres would still interpret it as such, leading to all kinds of odd behaviour, not to mention saving huge slabs of random bytes to your table, and probably segfaulting sooner or later...).

If your aim is to create a type which is internally represented as a simple integer (fixed-length, pass-by-value, etc.), you can just copy the characteristics of the built-in type:

```
CREATE TYPE gp (input=gp_input, output=gp_output, like=integer);
```

You should then be able to do away with the `palloc()` and the pointers, fetch your argument with `PG_GETARG_INT32(0)`, and just return `PG_RETURN_INT32(amt)`.

---

If you want all of the behaviour of a built-in type, but with a custom display format, it's a lot easier than you might expect.

The internal C routines for something like `numeric` are identical to the ones you'd write to implement such a type on your own. As as result, you can create your own version of such a built-in type simply by copy-pasting its SQL-level definitions, and leaving the functions pointing to the existing C handlers to do all of the actual work:

```
CREATE TYPE gp;
CREATE FUNCTION gp_in(cstring,oid,integer) RETURNS gp LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'numeric_in';
CREATE FUNCTION gp_out(gp) RETURNS cstring LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'numeric_out';
CREATE FUNCTION gp_send(gp) RETURNS bytea LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'numeric_send';
CREATE FUNCTION gp_recv(internal,oid,integer) RETURNS gp LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'numeric_recv';
CREATE FUNCTION gptypmodin(cstring[]) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'numerictypmodin';
CREATE FUNCTION gptypmodout(integer) RETURNS cstring LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS 'numerictypmodout';
CREATE TYPE gp (
  INPUT = gp_in,
  OUTPUT = gp_out,
  RECEIVE = gp_recv,
  SEND = gp_send,
  TYPMOD_IN = gptypmodin,
  TYPMOD_OUT = gptypmodout,
  LIKE = numeric
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE t (x gp(10,2), y gp);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('123.45', '2387456987623498765324.2837654987364987269837456981');
SELECT * FROM t;

   x    |                          y
--------+-----------------------------------------------------
 123.45 | 2387456987623498765324.2837654987364987269837456981
```

From there, you can replace the input/output handlers with your own C functions, copy-pasting the code from the [internal functions](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_2/src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c#L569) as a starting point. The simplest approach in your case is probably to transform your DnD currency string into a simple decimal string at the start of the function, and let the rest of the code worry about the messy details of converting it to a `Numeric`.

If you want arithmetic/comparison operators, index opclasses, min/max aggregates, typecasts, etc., you can copy-paste those definitions from the original type as well, as long as you don't mess with the internal binary format.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, to mimic `money`, this would be a variable-sized numeric, but accomplishing that seems very complicated and not well-documented.  So I guess for the moment, at least, I'll need to settle for fixed-size integral values.

It'd also be neat if I had any idea why these specific values had these problems.

Comment: Too much to fit in a comment; see the updated answer. `money` is fixed-length (8 bytes), so if you want variable-length values, you might want a `numeric` (I'm sure that someone in the history of D&D has managed to get hold of more than 2^64cp...).

Comment: You're right, there's almost nothing in the HTML docs about these low-level implementation details. But the source code is thoroughly commented, and since they build so much of the core functionality on top of their own APIs, there is usually no better explanation than the code itself. For pretty much anything you might want to do, you can find an example to imitate.

Comment: As for why specific values triggered this odd behaviour, I'm guessing it's because the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) mechanism hijacks a couple of `varlena` header bits indicate the storage mode, and within certain size ranges, it'll flip them fairly predictably. You might see them flip-flop around the boundaries, depending on the compressibility of the subsequent chunk of memory. But this is all guesswork based on your error message; I've never really had to dig in to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion.
I suppose it should be variable length, because you're right, somebody probably has gotten hold of more than that amount of money - or at least more than that in total including gear value. I would like to avoid making it a decimal, though that may not be realistic because I just found out last night that the price per unit for *Sling Bullets* is 0.2cp. I have no idea how you'd actually pay someone in-game that amount, since 1cp is the smallest denomination, but...

Comment: The built-in types are only a starting point. If you don't want the `(precision,scale)` parameters, you can just throw away the typmod handlers. And as long as your input function rejects anything with a decimal point, there's no realistic way to actually create a fractional value, even if your underlying data structure supports it (provided you don't blindly port `numeric`'s division operators, etc.). But if you'd rather not worry about any of this, you can just hijack `bigint` instead; nothing about this approach is specific to `numeric`.

Comment: As for the mechanics of spending 0.2cp, I'm sure someone over at [rpg.se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) is willing to explain it in excruciating detail ;)